# Построение дерева по Хаффману C#

Tags: c#, консоль

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace haffman
{
    class Program
    {
        public static List<Entry> CountingRepetition(string str, int param = 1)
        {
            var result = new List<Entry>();
            for (var i = 0; i <= (str.Length - param); i++)
            {
                var currentSegment = str.Substring(i, param);
                if (!result.Any(x => x.Data == currentSegment))
                {
                    result.Add(new Entry
                    {
                        Data = currentSegment,
                        Count = new Regex(Regex.Escape(currentSegment)).Matches(str).Count
                    });
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        static void DisplayTable(List<Entry> param)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            foreach (var disp in param)
            {
                Console.Write(disp.Data + "\t");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (var disp in param)
            {
                Console.Write(disp.Count + "\t");
                sum += disp.Count;
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            foreach (var disp in param)
            {
                Console.Write($"{disp.Count}/{sum}" + "\t");
            }
        }
        public static List<Entry> BuildThree(List<Entry> param)
        {
           // List<Entry> result = new List<Entry>();
            var sorted = param.OrderBy(u => u.Count);
            for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Count(); i++)
            {
                for (int j = i+1; j <= i+1; j++)
                {
                    if (param[i].Count >= param[j].Count)
                    {
                        Entry result = new Entry
                        {
                            Data = "*",
                            Count = param[i].Count + param[j].Count,
                            LeftSymbol = param[i].Data,
                            RightSymbol = param[j].Data,
                            LeftByte = 1,
                            RightByte = 0
                        };
                        param.Remove(param[i]);
                        j = 0;
                        param.Remove(param[j]);
                        param.Insert(0, result);
                        j++;
                    }
                    else if (param[i].Count < param[j].Count)
                    {
                        Entry result = new Entry
                        {
                            Data = "*",
                            Count = param[i].Count + param[j].Count,
                            LeftSymbol = param[j].Data,
                            RightSymbol = param[i].Data,
                            LeftByte = 0,
                            RightByte = 1
                        };
                        param.Remove(param[i]);
                        j = 0;
                        param.Remove(param[j]);
                        param.Insert(0,result);
                    }
                }
                i = -1;
            }
            return param;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Исходная строка: ");
            string sourceString = Console.ReadLine();

            //Подсчет кол-ва повторяющихся символов
            var countValues = CountingRepetition(sourceString, 1);
            Console.WriteLine("H(X)");
            DisplayTable(countValues);
            //
            BuildThree(countValues);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class Entry
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public int  Count { get; set; }
        public string LeftSymbol { get; set; }
        public string RightSymbol { get; set; }
        public byte LeftByte { get; set; }
        public byte RightByte { get; set; }
    }

}
```

### Написанная функция построения дерева работает неверно, могли бы подсказать что делаю не так, заранее спасибо!

Проблема заключается в коллекции param, в которой создаётся дерево. С первыми двумя выражениями все нормально. Как только в созданную ветвь пытаюсь добавить новое значение, в пункте left symbol отображается Entry,Entry...

Comment: Опишите подробнее - в чём заключается неверная работа?

Comment: Неверная работа заключается в том, что не могу собрать все 1 и 0 для имеющихся символов. Попробовал использовать массив строк или символов, данные затираются в массивах, а когда пытаюсь сделать что-то типа этого 'leftSymbol[i] = param[i].Data' выходит ошибка _Invalid initializer member declarator_

Comment: Есть идеи у когл?